# How can I stop an animator playing in Unity

Tags: animation, button, unity-game-engine, click, opacity

[SOLVED]

I have 4 buttons, each with a flashing opacity animation that I have rigged up to play when the button is clicked. However when a second button is playing, the one first clicked, still plays and flashes on. And that continues when more buttons are clicked. I have tried using loops, animation components rather than animators and a few other methods. Here is the code, could someone please tell me how I can stop the animation playing when another button is pressed?

```
public EnemyBehavior enemyBehavior;
    public bool[] difficultySelected;

    public Animator easy;
    public Animator normal;
    public Animator hard;
    public Animator expert;

    public void DifficultySelected(int name){
        difficultySelected[0] = false;
        difficultySelected[1] = false;
        difficultySelected[2] = false;
        difficultySelected[3] = false;
        difficultySelected[name] = true;
    }

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {
        if(difficultySelected[0] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 0.2f;
            easy.Play("Difficulty");
        }else if(difficultySelected[1] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 0.5f;
            normal.Play("Difficulty");
        }else if(difficultySelected[2] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 1;
            hard.Play("Difficulty");
        }else if(difficultySelected[3] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 2;
            expert.Play("Difficulty");
        }
    }
```

Update:

```
if(difficultySelected[0] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 0.2f;
            normal.StopPlayback();
            hard.StopPlayback();
            expert.StopPlayback();
            easy.Play("Difficulty");
        }else if(difficultySelected[1] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 0.5f;
            easy.StopPlayback();
            hard.StopPlayback();
            expert.StopPlayback();
            normal.Play("Difficulty");
        }else if(difficultySelected[2] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 1;
            easy.StopPlayback();
            normal.StopPlayback();
            expert.StopPlayback();
            hard.Play("Difficulty");
        }else if(difficultySelected[3] == true){
            enemyBehavior.shotsPerSecond = 2;
            easy.StopPlayback();
            normal.StopPlayback();
            hard.StopPlayback();
```

Comment: `StopPlayback()` won't work?

Comment: No, I've added an updated section to the description, would you mind checking that?

Comment: Have you tried easy.enable =  false;

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say of this, I tried that earlier with no success, but it all works now. Thanks!